# Data not showing from array

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays

I have fetched data from json into array but when i access array contents it does not show it shows in count two records but do not show the contents

```
for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++)
{
   id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
   NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
   ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
   [theObject setUser_id:[dict objectForKey:@"user_id"]];
   [theObject setSurvey_id:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_id"]];
   [theObject setSurvey_title:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Title"]];
   [theObject setSurvey_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Description"]]; 
   [theObject setDate_Created:[dict objectForKey:@"date_Created"]];

   NSString*testing=[dict objectForKey:@"survey_id"];
   NSLog(testing);

   [surveyList addObject:theObject];
   [theObject release];
   theObject=nil;

   int count =[surveyList count];
   NSLog(@"Total is %d",count);
}
```

I want to access like,

```
ObjectData*data=[surveyList objectAtIndex.path.row];
NSString*cellText=data.surveyDescription;
```

It does not show anything in cellText when NSLog,
I don't know why it is like that because array has contents.

```
   tempArray: (
    {
    color = "[UIColor GrayColor]";
    "date_created" = "2012-07-24 22:39:14";
    "survey_description" = "Survey To get feedback from clients about food quality and any suggestion to improve the service";
    "survey_id" = 1;
    "survey_title" = "Resturant Survey";
    "user_id" = ali40;
    },
    {
    color = "[UIColor greyColor]";
    "date_created" = "2012-07-25 00:43:42";
    "survey_description" = "Toursim Survey";
    "survey_id" = 2;
    "survey_title" = "Travel Servey";
    "user_id" = ali40;
   }
    )
```

Comment: are you reloading the table after filling the array.

Comment: What exactly do these NSLog produce?

Comment: Please add `NSLog(@"tempArray: %@", tempArray);` That will tell you the exact structure of the array and the object it contains including the keys of the dictionarys and their values.

Comment: Print NSLog as follows:NSLog(@"tempArray: %@", tempArray) and see what it is printing.As well as in cellForRowAtIndexPath where you are accessing your surveyList indexPath is stored in path?Use ObjectData*data=[surveyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];NSLog(@"desc:%@",data.surveyDescription);
  NSString*cellText=data.surveyDescription;

Comment: simple when i get any value from array it does not show i am not populating table now just to get value in NSString to see that array is giving data

Comment: BTW `theObject=nil;` does not harm here but it does not help either.

Comment: @HermannKlecker how to solve this issue

Comment: i have added the NSLog of tempArray

Comment: Thanks. Looks fine to me so far. The issue must be somewhere else I think. Now I would NSLog surveyList right after the for loop and right before accessing it and go from there.

Comment: Can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath code and as @ArunGJ suggested have you reloaded your table when data is received?

Comment: ok i am also adding that @Hermann Klecker

Comment: surveyList: (
    "<ObjectData: 0x6ab4c10>",
    "<ObjectData: 0x6ab5b90>"
)

Comment: its showing like this in surveyList

Comment: @HermannKlecker i have added surveyList NSLOg check that

Comment: @NuzhatZari actiually i think problem is in array surveyList i have shows NSLog please check that

Comment: That surveyList looks ok for me. You did not implement a display method for the object and that is why it is displayed with its address only. I am just ab bit confused by the parantheses. However, that may be ok. Well then, your surveyList is an array of two ObjectData objects. I would now go and nslog their contents in a for loop. ` for (DataObject *myObject in surveyList) {NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, myObject.user_id, myObject.survey_id, myObject_survey_title, myObject.survey_Description, myObject.date_Created);} `

Comment: I do not think problem is in your surveyList.Are you calling reloadTableView after this for loop?

Comment: @HermannKlecker how to remove this error now and shows the values og survey lsit

Comment: @NuzhatZari you are right problem is not in array there is issue in reloadTableView i am not doing like this

Comment: Whether you have to reload a the table or not depends on when this piece of code is executed. In loadView or viewDidLoad no reload table is required. You only reload the table (from data) when the table is displayed already and later the contents is supposed to change.

Comment: Did you fix the upper cases in your key strings? As a matter of fact you get lower cases delivered. See Amit Shah's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using

`"survery_Description"`

in your code, however the JSON only has

`"survey_description"`

(Note the non capitalisation)

Comment: And "date_created" as well. How come I'd overlooked that? However, an analyis of surveyList, as suggested above, woud have shown that these items are missing.